# Custom Fonts in TextView Throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently trying to implement custom fonts in a simple Welcome Slider Activity in an app I'm playing about with. However, I've tried implementing this the same way I've done it before but I keep getting a NullPointerException. I'm pretty sure everything is initialised so I can't see what the problem is. All help would be appreciated. I've included the complete class and xml files

```
package com.example.introslider;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
private TextView[] dots;
private int[] layouts;
private Button btnSkip, btnNext;
private PrefManager prefManager;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
    if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }

    // Making notification bar transparent
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);


    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_1);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/orbit.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(tf);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
    btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


    // layouts of all welcome sliders
    // add few more layouts if you want
    layouts = new int[]{
            R.layout.welcome_slide1,
            R.layout.welcome_slide2,
            R.layout.welcome_slide3,
            R.layout.welcome_slide4};

    // adding bottom dots
    addBottomDots(0);

    // making notification bar transparent
    changeStatusBarColor();

    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checking for last page
            // if last page home screen will be launched
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if (current < layouts.length) {
                // move to next screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        }
    });



}

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

    int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
    int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

    dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(35);
        dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if (dots.length > 0)
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}

private void launchHomeScreen() {
    prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}

//  viewpager change listener
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addBottomDots(position);

        // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
        if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
            // last page. make button text to GOT IT
            btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // still pages are left
            btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
            btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};

/**
 * Making notification bar transparent
 */
private void changeStatusBarColor() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

/**
 * View pager adapter
 */
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
}
```

And the XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mech">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/slide_1_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/slide_1_desc"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Stack Trace

```
04-08 20:23:08.386 20697-20697/com.example.introslider E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.introslider, PID: 20697
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.introslider/com.example.introslider.WelcomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.introslider.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:55)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: "but I keep getting a NullPointerException" -- please edit your question and post the full Java stack trace.

Comment: post your stack trace

Comment: Posted now. Thanks CommonsWare, Yohannes

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a typeface to your `TextView` but that `TextView` isn't in the `R.layout.activity_welcome` layout. That's why the reference is null and the app crashes

Comment: Sorry Lorenzo, I uploaded the wrong xml file, the "right" one is now attached.

Comment: This one doesn't include the `ViewPager` and the `Button`s. You can't use `findViewById` with `View`s you haven't inflated or you'll get a `NullPointerException`